# How to define a class for table to control the style of table rows

Tags: css, row, css-tables

I'm wondering if I can define a class that could also control the row styles within the table.

Lets say I define a class "aTable"

```
.aTable
{
  width:800px;
  border-spacing:2px;
}
```

I also want to define the row styles. So when I assign this class to a table, all the rows in that table would follow the design, let say background-color:#e9e9e9;

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
.aTable {
    width: 800px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
.aTable tr {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To give a whole row a background-color your would assign the background-color to each cell in that row, i.e.

```
.aTable tr td { background-color: #e9e9e9: }
```

You can always select specific classes or elements within a css class definition like that.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use [less](http://www.lesscss.org/) to make CSS a lot easier and cleaner. Then you could do this:

```
.aTable {
    width: 800px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    tr {
        background-color: #DDD;
    }
}
```

Comment: less has yet to earn w3c standard